# Можно ли как то сократить код но смысл не менять

Tags: javascript

Можно ли как то сократить код но смысл не менять.

```
let trexznachnoe = [],
chitirexznachnoe = [],
pyatiznashnoe = [];
let cifri = {
a: [100, 1000, 10000],
b: [200, 2000, 20000],
c: [300, 3000, 30000]
}

for(let cifra in cifri) {
for(let cif of cifri[cifra]){
    if(cif === 100 || cif === 200 || cif === 300){
        trexznachnoe.push(cif);
    }else{
        if(cif === 1000 || cif === 2000 || cif === 3000){
            chitirexznachnoe.push(cif);
        }else{
            if(cif === 10000 || cif === 20000 || cif === 30000){
                pyatiznashnoe.push(cif)
            }
        }
    }
 }
 }
 console.log(cifri);
 console.log("trexznachnoe: ", trexznachnoe);
 console.log("chitirexznachnoe: ", chitirexznachnoe);
 console.log("pyatiznashnoe: ", pyatiznashnoe);
```

Нужно сортировать по массивам 3=ех значение 4, и 5, по разным массивам и плюс если переместил в другой массив то удалить данное значение со старого массива

Comment: Кажется, тут нужны логарифмы...

Comment: Нужно просто написать как то с помощью cplice удалить со старого массива, а вот значения с if как то сократить

Comment: Для начала понять бы смысл. Напишите русским языком что тут происходит

Answer (score 3):

```
if (cif > 99 && cif < 1000) {
  trexznachnoe.push(cif);
} else if (cif > 999 && cif < 10000) { 
  chitirexznachnoe.push(cif);
} else if (cif > 9999 && cif < 100000) { 
  pyatiznashnoe.push(cif);
}
```

Comment: А как удалить со старого массива его данные которые переместили в другой массив

Comment: @КаренОганнисян не "со", а "из". Это уже другой вопрос, который не имеет отношения к вопросу, заданному выше. Задайте новый вопрос или просто посмотрите https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_splice.asp

Comment: Ну как удалить из старого массива его данные, которые были перемешены в другой массив

Comment: @КаренОганнисян, `cifri[cifra].splice(cifri[cifra].indexOf(cif), 1);` как-то так в вашем цикле)